The page doen't load at all | ANGULAR 18 IONIC 7.2.0
I have a project in capacitor, which was previously from Cordova, that when I want to navigate to another page, the interface does not fully load until I do a reload, but that is not a good technique, and it also does not work for me since I use a SharedInfo service and when reloading it is lost the information.
I have tried with the ChangeDetectorRef with the detectChanges, it does not work, with the ngzone, it does not work, I have a lazy load and I have the preload of the routes in PreloadAllModules, and it does not work either.
No message appears in the console, and for example, on pages like the one I have for a QR scanner, it loads part of the interface except the camera, and you see the background, which is the previous window. On the other pages, it does not load anything until the page is reloaded. It's a very strange problem, but I've tried everything and nothing works for me anymore. The error happened to me migrating from Cordova to Capacitor, at first it didn't compile, now it does but that's it, the navigation is broken or the DOM.
What can I do?

It is very hard for us to be able to help without having more details. Have you tried cutting down parts of the project to reduce the amount of code and be able to pin point more closely where the problem comes from? Are there no error in the devtools console?
